# Spec looking for specific HTML tag does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm working on a rails application and want to test using capybara, so far I had no problem but now that I'm implementing a markdown parsing feature I cant make my test pass.

I added this test

```
it "Shows makdown as HTML" do
  visit_wiki
  expect(page).to have_tag('pre')  //**EDITED** becauseof typo
end
```

And I can't make it work, `visit_wiki` is just a method to well... visit the wiki.

```
def visit_wiki
  visit topics_path
  click_link topic.name
  click_link sentence
  expect(current_path).to eq topic_wiki_path(@wiki.topic, @wiki.id)
end
```

I know that works because I've been using that in other parts of this project.

Here is also my Factory where I make sure to always have one `pre` HTML tag.

```
require 'random_data'
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :wiki do
    title Faker::Lorem.sentence
    body  RandomData.random_md
    private false
    topic
    user
  end
end

//where random_md is

module RandomData
    def self.random_md
        md = []
        md << Faker::Markdown.headers
        md << Faker::Markdown.block_code
        rand(4..10).times do
            md << Faker::Markdown.random
        end
        md.join("\n")
    end
end
```

From that factory I'm able to seed data and display it correctly on my site.
I even tried this from [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers/RSpec%2FHtmlMatchers%3Ahave_tag) website:

```
expect("<html>
  <body>
    <h1>some html document</h1>
  </body>
 </html>").to have_tag('body')
```

still, fails...

I guess I must be doing something wrom but don't know what, I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
This is how body looks:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h2>Labore</h2>
      .
      .
      .
      <div class="highlight">
        <pre>
            <span class="no">Quo</span> 
            <span class="n">voluptates</span>
            <span class="n">et</span> 
            <span class="n">et</span> 
            <span class="n">excepturi</span> 
            <span class="n">sit</span>
            <span class="o">.</span>
         </pre>
      </div>
      .
      .
      .
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What fails? What's the error message?

Comment: Also, is `expect(page).to body have_tag('pre')` correct? That looks like a typo to me; shouldn't that be `expect(page.body).to have_tag('pre')`?

Comment: @TomLord yes sorry, it should be like `expect(page).to have_tag('pre')`, small typo I'll edit the question. Still, that was not the problem. And no error message, just `17 examples, 1 failure`

Comment: So if the failure is in the `expect(page)......` line, then that *is* the value of `page`?

Comment: just edited the question @TomLord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_tag` is not Capybara provided and isn't what you should be using with Capybara.  This is because the `have_tag` matcher provided by rspec-html-matchers, grabs the page source as a string at time of call, parses it with nokogiri, and then queries against it.  That neuters the waiting/retrying behavior Capybara provides and will lead to unstable/non-working tests, not to mention the extra overhead that produces for every query.  What you want is `have_css`/`have_xpath`/`have_selector`

```
expect(page).to have_css('pre')
```

A second issue in your test code is that you shouldn't be using `current_path` with the `eq` matcher, rather you should be using the `have_current_path` matcher which utilizes Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(topic_wiki_path(@wiki.topic, @wiki.id))
```

Comment: Thanks! that was awesome, also thank you for correcting my path error, I have it everywhere, I'll change it now.